# What should I do about DApp?

Tags: flutter, mobile, blockchain, solidity

Do I need something like Solidity for DApp in my mobile wallet application (that I am currently programming with Flutter) or can I just hard-code it?

Comment: You do need solidity and deployed contracts to communicate with blockchain with web3.dart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use solidity ( or any other smart contract language ) to create the smart contract (backend), and then you can use flutter to create the app (frontend).

Then you can use a library to connect your app with your contract such as web3dart.

Contracts are stored and executed by the blockchain, and thus can't be hardcoded into frontend applications.

Comment: Thank you. You gave me the answer I'd rather not to hear. I better go for Soliditiy.